# Section ID id is Visible in text with jquery replace function

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm using the replace function to replace a div. Using something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#electricalengineering").click(function() {
    $("#section1").replaceWith("#section2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1">
  <p>First Div</p>
  <a href="#">
    <p id="electricalengineering">Electrical Engineering</p>
  </a>
</div>
<div id="section2">
  <p>Second Div</p>
</div>
```

Strangely, upon clicking, the #section2 is visible as text. Any ideas?

Here is the [Working Example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMDJ0WBW8NHW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string, rather than the jquery object you were planning on.

Rather than `"#section2"` replace it with `$("#section2")` as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#electricalengineering").click(function(){
    $("#section1").replaceWith($("#section2"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="section1">
<p>First Div</p>
<a href="#"><p id="electricalengineering">Electrical Engineering</p></a>
</div>
<div id="section2">
<p>Second Div</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Great then please upvote/accept one of the answers given so the question can be marked as resolved. Glad we were able to help

Comment: Done. Do you know how I can have the second div hidden until click? Or should I start a new thread?

Comment: Nevermind, figure it out. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

When passing `"#section2"` you are passing a string not the content of `#section2`

try passing it a jquery object instead

```
$("#section1").replaceWith($("#section2"));
```